# Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes low but Memory\Pool Paged Bytes high

Tags: sql-server, perfmon

Can someone help identify how these values can indicate memory leak.

In the system I am monitoring `Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes` are low (on average 100mb) but `Memory\Pool Paged Bytes` are high (on average 280mb).

I read somewhere that these numbers should be under 150 and 250 respectively otherwise it indicates memory leaks. What are your thoughts? what other memory counters should i look at to say that 280mb is high and indicative of memory leak issues?

Comment: Please tag your question with sql server version. Also, update your question with more details like problem you are facing, errors, server spec, etc

Comment: This is sql server 2012 SP1. I am just looking at some perfmon counters and seeing this value so wondering if there is a problem indicatives through these numbers or some other counters should be looked (if so, which ones).

Comment: Free memory quantities should never be considered indicative of a memory leak, by themselves.  There are no specific quantities of free paged/non-paged pool that would automatically indicate a memory leak.  If free memory (any kind) continues to shrink over time, resulting in the system halting or "blue screening", I might begin to suspect a memory leak.

Comment: Are you seeing any memory related error in event viewer ? What for what tool you are trying to find out whether it is leaking memory or not. If it is SQL Server, unless it is SQL Server bug it does leaks memory. Your question seems related to windows why have you tagged it to SQL Server ?